# How to create factorial in Java with explanation

Tags: java, factorial

Greetings people of the internet!

I'm a newbie in Java. I have a question about creating factorial.

I was able to create a factorial that only shows the result. I have the syntax here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DynamicFact {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int anc = 1;
    double fact = 1;
    System.out.println("Enter your number : ");
    int num = sc.nextInt();

    if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("Your number is not valid. Please enter another number.");
    } else {
        for (anc = 1; anc <= num; anc++) {
            fact = fact * anc;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial " + num + " is = " + fact );
    }

}
}
```

And the output is (for example the number is 6): Factorial 6 is = 720.0

But can somebody help me to make the output look like this:
Factorial 6 is 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 720.0. 
Or if the user wanted a number 7, the output would be:
Factorial 7 is 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 5040.0

and so on.

Your help would be very appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hint: Have a look at `StringBuilder`.

Comment: (Unrelated to question) "Your number is not valid. Please enter another number." - Imagine you are a user that does not know the code. What would you ask?

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuilder to build up the arithmetic expression as you go:

```
} else {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (anc = 1; anc <= num; anc++) {
        if(anc > 1)sb.append(" * ");
        sb.append(anc);
        fact = fact * anc;
    }
    sb.append(" = ").append(fact);
    System.out.println("Factorial " + num + " is " + sb);
}
```

Comment: Actually, to get the exact output from question, you'd have to go from `num` down to 1 instead of 1 to `num`.

Comment: You could use `sb.insert(0, ` for that. For some reason the Java bods didn't include a `prepend` method on the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Bathsheba One possibility, yes. Personally though, I'd find it more logical to follow the order of the output. And it isn't as much as changing the for ( huah, nearly spoiled the exercise ... )

Comment: @Bathsheba the reason is probably that the time complexity would be appalling. StringBuilder is array-based, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution you can use :

```
String result = "", separator = "";
for (anc = 1; anc <= num; anc++) {
    fact = fact * anc;
    result = anc + separator + result;
    separator = " * ";
}
System.out.println("Factorial " + num + " is " + result + " = " + fact);
```

This will show you for 6 `Factorial 6 is 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 720.0`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int anc = 1;
    double fact = 1;

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println("Enter your number : ");
    int num = sc.nextInt();

    if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("Your number is not valid. Please enter another number.");
    } else {
        for (anc = 1; anc <= num; anc++) {
            fact = fact * anc;
            result.insert(0,Integer.toString(anc)+"*");
        }

        System.out.println("Factorial " + num + " is = " + fact );
        System.out.println(result.substring(0,result.length()-1));
    }

}
}
```